# Eliminating Loop in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

How do I rework the query below to eliminate the `foreach` loop and make a single call to the database?

```
List<AuditLog> auditLogs = new List<AuditLog>();

foreach (TableRecordGuidPair pair in allTablesRecords)
{
    var auditLogsFromDatabase = databaseContext.AuditLog.OrderBy(x => x.EventDateUtc)
      .Where
        (x => x.TableName == pair.TableName && 
         x.RecordId == pair.RecordID)
        .Select(auditLog => new AuditLog
        {
            AuditLogId = auditLog.AuditLogId,
        }).ToList();
    auditLogs.AddRange(auditLogsFromDatabase);
}

return auditLogs;
```

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Ha! If I had it at work I would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SelectMany to select all of the lists like so:

```
return allTablesRecords
    .SelectMany(pair => 
        databaseContext.AuditLog.OrderBy(x => x.EventDateUtc)
            .Where(x => x.TableName == pair.TableName && x.RecordId == pair.RecordID)
            .Select(auditLog => new AuditLog
            {
                AuditLogId = auditLog.AuditLogId,
            })
    )
    .ToList();
```

Alternatively, you can do a join

```
return (from allTableRecords pair
    join databaseContext.AuditLog auditLog
        on new { pair.TableName, pair.RecordId } equals new { auditLog.TableName, auditLog.RecordId }
    select new {
        AutitLogId = auditLog.AuditLogId
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: First option needs a `.ToList()` before the semicolon. This seems to clean up the syntax, but is still making `n` calls, where `n` is the `.Count` of `allTablesRecords`

Comment: so `allTableRecords` isn't coming from the database? Or it's some in-memory structure?

Comment: `allTablesRecords` is being passed in through the method signature. It is a list of an object that contains only those two strings.

Comment: I'm not totally sure there is a good way to do this in linq only. You might want to write a stored procedure that can create a temp table to join on.

Answer (score 1):

Make a projection of keys with a wild card from allTablesRecords, and then compare it using contains in the query. This works only when allTablesRecords only has less than about 5000 records. If it is more than that, you are going to probably encounter runtime exceptions, and should consider making a stored procedure.

```
IEnumerable<string> pairKeys = allTablesRecords.Select(pair => pair.TableName + "¿" + pair.RecordID);
return databaseContext.AuditLog.OrderBy(x => x.EventDateUtc)
    .Where(x => pairKeys.Contains(x.TableName + "¿" + x.RecordID))
    .Select(auditLog => new AuditLog
    {
        AuditLogId = auditLog.AuditLogId,
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: interesting use of a unicode character to match fields.

Comment: @DLeh - alt+4008 . It was just to make sure things like apple + 5 and appl + e5  don't match.

Comment: yeah. I usually would just use a `:` or something, but this would be a bit less likely to cause issues. Of course, I wouldn't do this if i knew the character could be present in the string I'm searching